# string/char comparison vs. bitwise comparison in python

Tags: python, string, comparison, neural-network, bit-manipulation

I have a large data set of nucleotide sequences (long strings simply put) which converts into a 104*13440 matrix full of characters. My project forces me to do degenerate string matching while exploring all possible states/oppertunities (i-e no fancy heuristics and/or screening). Since the data set is so large, manually checking all the word tuples character by character is very frustrating and computationally complex.

Will converting characters to respective binary, and implementing minor neural networks using bitwise comparisons save processing time and memory consumption, as compared to simple character comparison?

I am using python 3.

Forgot to mention, word tuples are overlapping, with size ranging from 15-25 characters/tuple, so you can see the dilemma

Comment: forgot to mention, word tuples are overlapping, with size ranging from 15-25 characters/tuple, so you can see the dilemma..

Comment: don't make comments explaining the question, edit the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Will converting characters to
>   respective binary, and implementing
>   minor neural networks using bitwise
>   comparisons save processing time and
>   memory consumption, as compared to
>   simple character comparison?

No. Introducing something as complex as a neural network to solve string comparison is going to take way longer.

If you want to make your code faster, I recommend posting it on http://codereview.stackexchange.com, where the people there will tell you what you can do to make it faster.

Comment: @W.Ewert: noted. What if i skipped on the neural network and just used bitwise comparisons iteratively?

Comment: @SHKT, I'm not 100% sure what are you thinking, but comparing characters is fast, converting to binary and comparing that will almost certainly be slower. But seriously, the best way to get advice on speeding up the code is to post it on codereview